# Python Multiprocessing Looping Python File Instead of Starting Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get started with multiprocessing, and I'm running into some interesting issues. The code I'm using is below (for the record, this example is straight from the multiprocessing documentation):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
     print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     p = Process(target=f, args=('bob'))
     p.start()
     p.join()
```

This works fine, and prints "hello bob" as it should. When I add any additional code to the file though, before or after the if statement, then p does not evaluate, and my file loops back to the beginning and runs all over again endlessly. For example, the following code gives me this issue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
     print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     p = Process(target=f, args=('bob'))
     p.start()
     p.join()

test_input = input("test input")
```

I am running Python using Windows 10, Pycharm v. 2021.3.2, and Python 3.10.0. Is this an issue that any of you have seen before? At this point I'm starting to wonder if perhaps it's even an issue between Windows and Pycharm or Windows and Python, or maybe just a case of inexperience on my part.

Thank you!

Comment: "loops back to the beginning and runs all over again endlessly", try to put `input()` call inside `f()` and check what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is important. On systems that don't use `fork`, it simulates a `fork` by importing the main script in each worker process *without* naming it `__main__` (it's named `__mp_main__` IIRC). Any code that should only run in the "main" script needs to be protected by that guard (it can be indirectly, by defining a function and calling it within the guarded segment; the function will be defined in the workers, but not run).

So to fix this, all you need to do is indent the `test_input = input("test input")` so it's protected by the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. In real code, I try to keep the guarded section clean (so I can't accidentally write functions that rely on global state that doesn't exist when it's not run as the main script, and for the mild performance benefits of using function locals over globals), so I'd write it like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

def main():
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    test_input = input("test input")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: This solved the issue beautifully, thank you! No more endlessly looping modules!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would elaborate on ShadowRanger's answer:

On Windows systems new subprocesses are created by the following steps:

1. A new process is created wherein the Python interpreter is re-launched.
2. The Python interpreter re-interprets the current source program executing *everything* that is at global scope in order to compile function definitions, initialize global variables, etc.
3. Finally, your worker function, `f` in this case, is invoked with memory thus initialized.

The reason for placing the code that creates the subprocess within a block that is governed by `if __name__ == '__main__':` is that if you didn't, then because of Step 2 above you would get into a recursive, infinite loop creating new subprocesses *ad inifinitum*. **The key point is that only in the main function will variable `__name__` have the value '__main__'; it will have a different value for any subprocess that is created.** And so the code that creates the new subprocess, i.e. `p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))`, will not be executed as part of the initialization of the subprocess.

Your problem arises from the statement `test_input = input("test input")` being at global scope *and* not being within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and so it will be executed as part of the initialization of the subprocess. So your worker function, `f`, will not run until this prompt for input is satisfied and then when it returns your main process will be putting out the prompt again. Anyway, this is what I see when the program is run from a Windows command prompt. Perhaps with PyCharm there is a restriction against doing the **input** statement from any thread other than the main thread. But even if an exception is being thrown from that statement in creating the subprocess, I still don't quite see how your program would be looping continuously. Unfortunately, I do not have PyCharm installed.

Comment: Thank you! That actually makes a lot of sense. This is the first time I've really had to deal with Windows' quirks in how it interacts with Python, so the explanation is really helpful. Actually, your explanation solves a couple mysteries I was having with older projects as well. Since the new subprocesses were being created recursively, it was eating my computer's memory into oblivion. Thank you again!

Comment: @thedavincicoder: To be clear, this isn't a Windows-specific quirk. Any program using the `'spawn'` or `'forkserver'` startmethods (due to OS default or opting in) will have the same problem. It used to be Windows was the only OS defaulting to `'spawn'`, but in 3.8 they started doing the same for macOS (many of the macOS system libraries higher-level than libc [turned out not to be fork-safe](https://bugs.python.org/issue33725)), and even on *NIX and other OSes defaulting to `'fork'`, any program can opt in to the other launch methods and have this problem.

Comment: The docs do include [a fairly detailed set of guidelines on what you must do to write a `multiprocessing` program using `'spawn'` or `'forkserver'` correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods); I'd strongly suggest reading them to avoid other issues.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger! The documentation you attached will help me steer clear of the rocks as I continue to make more complex programs utilizing multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to ShadowRanger answer, I think you should also put comma after 'bob'.
According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

P should be like this if you want to put another statement.

```
  p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
```

Comment: My apologies, I was recreating the code in this question on a different device, and I missed typing the comma into the tuple. It's there in my actual code! Thank you!